# Private including header file

Tags: c++

I have header file **A** that includes header file **B** to get functions but i want when include header **A** not access functions of header **B**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Trivial. If any functions DEFINED in *A* access functions declared in *B*, then declare those functions without defining them in the *A*, and define them elsewhere (e.g. a separate source file). If you do that properly, there should be no need for header *A* to include *B* at all  (the source file that defines functions in *A* will need to include both headers).  If you insist on those function definitions being in header *A*, then there is no solution. It may be possible to move those functions into another header and include that, but (to a compiler) that's the same as what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to deal with the problem.

1. Create file `C.h`. The contents of `C.h` must be minimized so that it only has what's absolutely essential for use in `A.h`
2. Include `C.h` in `A.h` **and** `B.h`.